# How to use step size in angular-star-rating module in angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML:-

```
<star-rating
    class="large"
    [starType]="'svg'"
    [rating]="4.3"
    [readOnly]="true"
    [step]="0.1"
    [showHalfStars]="true"
    [staticColor]="'positive'"
    [hoverEnabled]="false">
</star-rating>
```

If I use `[showHalfStars]="true"`, then it will be ***fine for .5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5, but its not working with step
If I set 4.3*** and many more, it should show 4 stars fill and .3 portion of the fifth star should be filled too.

App Module TS File:-

```
import { StarRatingModule } from 'angular-star-rating';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    StarRatingModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [MyComponent],

  providers: [
    MyService
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Star Rating Module in Github](https://github.com/BioPhoton/angular-star-rating)